# simple way to plot raw 3d coordinates

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, vector-graphics

I'm trying to reverse engineer some opengl calls and I have some raw vertex data. I want to plot some of this data as 3D coordinates in order to produce a mesh. Since I don't know how the vertices are supposed to fit together, the tool should assume all vertices connect to all other vertices and then display the surface of the resulting solid. Ideally, I should be able to rotate the view so I can see what it looks like from different angles. Are there any free and easy to use tools for this? what's the best option?

Comment: Any reason you're not just drawing all your vertices as a point cloud in raw OpenGL?

Comment: @Mario well, for one thing I've never actually programmed anything in OpenGL, I just started learning the functions a couple of days ago. What is a point cloud, and how do I do that? The call trace that apitrace generates has thousands of calls per frame, so It's a bit overwhelming to figure out what it all means.

Comment: "Point cloud" is a somewhat funny word for `GL_POINTS`. Kind of like "triangle soup", in that it means a series of unconnected primitives.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. So you have a list of vertices and you don't know how they are connected with each to form polygons? But you know theses are the vertices of some polygons? I don't see how you can draw an 3D object if you don't know how the vertices are connected to each other to form faces!? Or are you talking about using OpenGL to display vertices as points as other people said?

Answer (score 1):

You could most likely just use a point cloud together with some basic viewport/matrix setup (look it up please).

A point cloud is really just that: A collection of points in 2D or 3D space.

To draw one in classic OpenGL you can do something as simple as the following (note that this requires an older context version and/or compatibility context; it's not directly supported on OpenGL ES):

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    // Now, for each of your vertices, just submit the coordinates:
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);

glEnd();
```

Comment: hmm, I would like to avoid writing a program here though. However, apitrace lets you insert calls into the trace and then play it back. Starting from `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,...,..., GL_STATIC_DRAW)` how would I get to a draw call?

Comment: Your vertices are in that buffer?

Comment: yeah, though I don't how the attributes are layed out, ie which elements are coordinates. I do know the number of attributes per vertex though (I was able to figure it out by factoring the number of elements). I have some clues to the attributes though and was hoping visualization would help with that.

Comment: Have a look at this example, which utilizes array buffers (they're using indexes as well though): http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples - As for the vertex format: Trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

> the tool should assume all vertices connect to all other vertices

You don't want to do that. The complexity of this is factorial which grows really, really fast:

```
 0!      1  
 1!      1
 2!      2
 3!      6
 4!      24
 5!      120
 6!      720
 7!      5040
 8!      40320
 9!      362880
10!      3628800
11!      39916800
12!      479001600
13!      6227020800
14!      87178291200
15!      1307674368000
16!      20922789888000
17!      355687428096000
18!      6402373705728000
19!      121645100408832000
20!      2432902008176640000
21!      51090942171709440000
22!      1124000727777607680000
23!      25852016738884976640000
24!      620448401733239439360000
25!      15511210043330985984000000
26!      403291461126605635584000000
27!      10888869450418352160768000000
28!      304888344611713860501504000000
29!      8841761993739701954543616000000
30!      265252859812191058636308480000000
```

Your best bet would probably be a simple point cloud. You can use some Delaunay triangulation to get a surface back.

Comment: thanks for the info. Though, what I'm really looking for is something that someone has already made.

Comment: @MattMunson: What you're asking for is very unspecific. Surely nobody will have made a serious implementation of *"draw a line from each every vertex to every other vertex"* simply because this doesn't scale very well. Also the result of this will be an inrecognizable mess; I once had a bug in one of my programs that would mess up the index array of a wireframe rendering resulting in vertices connected with lines all over the place. You could hardly guess what the shape of the original object was. Point clouds are far superior for this. In OpenGL it's a simple `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, …)`

Comment: I'm happy to use point clouds. But I'd still rather have a tool instead of programming it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to learn about perspective projection. You will need to write some code. But the idea is to create a perspective projection matrix and to project your points using this matrix. The whole process is explained here:

http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/perspective-projection-matrix/

You will even find an example of program that does just want you want. Takes a list of 3D points and project them onto the screen. You may need to transform your points in 3D space (using a world to camera matrix) before the perspective projection.

Then the program save the result to a PPM file (and image).

Comment: No, that's not really what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to pull some game coordinates from a trace. To do that I need to know which vertex buffer to look in, and to know that it would be convenient to somehow be able visualize the data. But if I there's not a tool that already exists to help me do that, I will probly try a different approach.